# MVC Pauses before Controller / Action execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

We have a brown field MVC 5 running on a Web Role in Azure which was recently upgraded to 4.6.1 and MVC 5.2.6 to help us run Application Insights. We've got our telemetry running beautifully, but we're seeing weird spikes in our request processing times. It appears to be random and across all requests in about 3% of cases. The image attached shows the timeline.

Anyone have an idea why IIS / ASP.NET would be pausing after Execute Request Handler? This one takes a full 1 minute while the server holds the request before the contents of the action is invoked (you can see the CosmosDb calls take only a few milliseconds at the end). The action has very little in it other than calls to storage, so this is definitely an issue in the MVC pipeline.

Thoughts appreciated!

[Application Telemetry Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LmEp.png)

Comment: Could it be the telemetry?  Or anything else in your middleware: authentication, logging, ...

Comment: Pretty standard out of the box / OWIN asp.net Identity based authentication, with some custom Authorization and action filters - though those are all in memory or using claims, so no IO. The Telemetry is being turned off tonight, just in case it IS the telemetry. Though obviously a nice little catch 22 there!